# Error: make: *** No rule to make target `.f90', needed by `.o'. Stop

Tags: gcc, makefile, fortran

I'm trying to run a case for the **software [ExoPlaSim]** (https://github.com/alphaparrot/ExoPlaSim) on my **MacBook**.
While the software is built primarily for Linux, it can run on Mac according to the developer instructions. I've installed the software and (as far as I can tell) the necessary dependencies per the instructions on the website. I'm running a simple script (see below) to test that all is working. It isn't—I get errors. **The first significant error I get is this:**

`Writing makefile...`
`` make: *** No rule to make target `.f90', needed by `.o'.  Stop. ``

**What's going on? What's the problem here?** From my online research it looks like possible problems may include:

- ".f90" file can't be found.
- Compiler version is incorrect.
- The directory structure is wrong.

These are all basically guesses on my part. I could be way off base. The software is functional (other users confirm it works for them, though on Linux) and the initial case I'm trying to run is very basic and without any errors (that I can see).

**The case (python file) is this:**

```py
import exoplasim as exo
mymodel = exo.Model(workdir="mymodel_testrun",modelname="mymodel",resolution="T21",layers=5,precision=4,ncpus=2)
mymodel.configure()
mymodel.run(years=10,crashifbroken=True)
mymodel.finalize("mymodel_output")
```

The directory structure for the case is: `/Users/username/ExoPlaSim_Testing` (`ExoPlaSim_Testing` is an arbitrary directory I created to store case files).

The path containing the software (as far as I can tell) is: `/Users/username/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/exoplasim`.

*** I'm a casual developer (mostly some front-end stuff): **Answers should not assume too much prior dev knowledge**. ***

Thank you!!!

Comment: It appears that the Python module you're using is writing out a makefile then running make on that makefile, and that makefile is not well-formed in some way.  Based on the information here that's about all we can say.  That error looks very strange to me.

Comment: `.f90` is among the conventional extensions for Fortran source files.  The makefile is assuming that at least one such file is among those it should compile, but it does not find it.  Off the top of my head, that might be because you have an incomplete package, or because *you* are expected to provide the file yourself, or because the script is supposed to create it but doesn't, or because it is looking in (maybe running in) the wrong directory.

Comment: Actually, looking a bit closer, something seems to be more deeply wrong here.  The makefile seems to think that it should compile a file named exactly `.f90`, which suggests that some variable somewhere did not get a value.  This is probably a more involved problem than we are prepared to solve.  I suggest contacting the software maintainer(s) for support.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I contacted the developer many weeks ago, but no luck on a reply. I may try again if stackoverflow doesn't provide a solution. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnBollinger This is perplexing to me, since from speaking with another user of the software, and reading the documentation, I shouldn't need to supply any additional info than I have. And the software SHOULD work. It works for other users. So I presume I have some dependency problem, or maaaaybe some issue with the arrangement of relevant directories. Am I way off base here? (I have no experience with make files).

Comment: @MadScientist Could this be an issue with fortran itself? Maybe using the wrong version?  Or perhaps the "Fortran-compatible libraries" I was supposed to build (for Mac compatibility) weren't built correctly? With that hypothesis align with this error?

Comment: No.  The problem is from make: it can't figure out how to build a file.  Nothing about fortran or libraries or whatever is involved: you're not even getting to the point where the fortran compiler is invoked by make.  As I mentioned above, and John also noticed, "the error looks very strange".  It looks to me like either (a) the generated makefile is malformed, or (b) there's a bug in your version of GNU make.

Comment: Since you're using Mac and Apple is well-known for hating on GNU software, if you're using the version of GNU make that comes with MacOS, which is known to be old and buggy, I suppose the simple option to determine if that's the problem is use MacPorts or Brew to install a shiny modern new version of GNU make and see if that works any better (or you can build it yourself).  I have no idea if this will help, but it can't hurt.

Comment: @MadScientist Upgraded gcc on my Mac from 11.2 to 11.3 No difference.

Comment: I didn't say anything about GCC.  I said GNU make.

Comment: @MadScientist I apologize...don't know how I read that wrong. I did as you suggested and upgraded to GNU Make 4.3. No change in the error. :-/ Long shot any way I guess.

Comment: Can you look in the folder where working files are being created and find a file that's named something like Makefile and add the contents to the question. Are there any .f90, .f or .f77files in the exoplasim directory or subs and what are the relative paths

Comment: @Cocofalco When I try to run the case file, two subdirectories are created in my case file's parent directory (/Users/username/ExoPlaSim_Testing/...). The two subs are: "mymodel_testrun" and "mymodel_crashed". Testrun is empty (I think if the model had run successfully the output files would be here). Crashed contains a lot of files, but nothing like "Makerfile." There is a Unix executable called "most_plasim_run". In the software directory  (/Users/username/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/exoplasim) there are many files ending in .f90. Does this answer your questions?